# ParseError in None: not a BitBake file

Tags: yocto, bitbake

When I try to "bitbake some_recipe"

The error raised like below.
"ParseError in None: not a BitBake file"

Do you know how to debug it and which files is problem?

Comment: show the recipe

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: simliar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474984/how-to-solve-error-parseerror-in-recipe-name-not-a-bitbake-file